# Where can I find ProjectRemainingWork in CSOM API

Tags: csom, project-server, pwa

When I access https://[sharepoint]/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects I see "ProjectRemainingWork" as a field. How can I retrieve this field if I query Project Server via ProjectContext?

My code:

```
using (var clientContext = new ProjectContext(SharePointSite))
{
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Login, GetSecurePWD(PWD));
            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Projects);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var project in clientContext.Projects)
            {
                  Console.WriteLine(project.Name);
                  // & RemainingWork: Console.WriteLine(project.RemainingWork);          
            }
}
```

*Update: ah, I'm not interested in EAC, it was a mistake. Only RemaingWork is important*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is possible. In theory this data is available via the project's summary [task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.projectserver.client.task.remainingwork_di_pj14mref.aspx). But according to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecb6eec6-95c4-4ade-a8c2-d58253e7be49/csom-project-summary-task?forum=project2010custprog) and [this](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2015/07/16/how-to-read-project-properties-that-are-not-available-in-the-client-object-model/), the summary task is not available via CSOM.